# Get particular value for each <input>

Tags: javascript, jquery

So this is the case.

I have 2 `<input>` inside `<td>` which has unlimited number. For example :

```
<td>
   <input type="text" name="cust_name" onchange="check(this)" />
   <input type="hidden" name="cust_id" value="10" />
</td>
<td>
   <input type="text" name="cust_name" onchange="check(this)" />
   <input type="hidden" name="cust_id" value="12" />
</td>
......
```

`this` in `check(this)` containing `cust_name` value. But how can I get particular `cust_id` value with same function? (`check()`)

Delineation :

```
function check(part_element){
   console.log($(part_element).val());
   console.log(getting particular cust_id value); //here is the part
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You  can use `next`

```
function check(part_element){
   console.log($(part_element).val());
   console.log($(part_element).next().val()); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use [.next()](http://api.jquery.com/next/) to find the next sibling, in this case it is the `cust_id` element

```
function check(part_element){
   console.log($(part_element).val());
   console.log($(part_element).next().val()); //here is the part
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This already has an accepted answer, but in this case I'd argue that using jQuery doesn't make this any easier, possibly even more complicated:

```
function check(el) {
    console.log(el.value);
    console.log(el.nextSibling.value);
}
```